# find $k^2$ if $\left| a\sin^2 \theta+b\sin \theta \cos \theta+c\cos^2 \theta-\frac{(a+c)}{2} \right|=\frac{k}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $
> \left|
>   a\sin^2\theta+b\sin\theta\cos\theta+c\cos^2\theta-\dfrac{(a+c)}{2}
> \right|=\dfrac{k}{2}$, then find $k^2.$

**My Attempt**
\begin{align}
  \pm k &= 2a\sin^2 \theta+2b\sin \theta \cos \theta+2c\cos^2 \theta-(a+c) \\
  &= a[1-\cos 2\theta]+b\sin 2\theta+c[1+\cos 2\theta]-(a+c) \\
  &=  a\left[ 1-\frac{1-\tan^2 \theta}{1+\tan^2 \theta} \right]+
  b\frac{2\tan \theta}{1+\tan^2 \theta}+
  c\left[ 1+\frac{1-\tan^2 \theta}{1+\tan^2 \theta} \right]-(a+c)\\
  \pm k[1+\tan^2 \theta]  &=
  2a\tan^2 \theta+2b\tan \theta+2c-(a+c)[1+\tan^2 \theta] \\
  0 &= \tan^2 \theta [a-c\mp k]+2b\tan \theta+(c-a\mp k) \\
  \Delta &= 4b^2-4(a-c\mp k)(c-a\mp k) \\
  &= 4b^2-4[\mp k+(a-c)][\mp k-(a-c)] \\
  &= 4b^2-4[k^2-(a-c)^2] \\
  & \ge 0 \\
  b^2+(a-c)^2 & \ge k^2
\end{align}

How do I prove that $k^2=b^2+(a-c)^2$ ?

Comment: $$2a\sin^2t+2b\sin t\cos t+2c\cos^2t-(a+c)=\cos2t(c-a)+b\sin2t\le\sqrt{b^2+(c-a)^ 2}$$   I think you need minimum value of $k$

Comment: You can not prove $k^2=b^2+(a-c)^2$, because for $\theta = 0$, $k^2=(c-a)^2$.